# Make inline-block shrink to contents on overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an inline-block container, with several other inline-block elements like so:
[image: As working]

The container is the blue background, the red the elements. Everything is working fine until there's too many elements and the inline-block has to expand:
[image: As not working]

The inline-block container expands to the entire width of the body, but I want it to shrink to the width of it's contents. Is this possible with pure CSS? Kinda like this:
[image: As I want it to work]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eRHnp/)

```
        #container {
            background: blue;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .box {
            background: red;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
```

Oh, and the container can't be a fixed width :(

Comment: Are you opposed to defining a width for the container?

Comment: @asifrc can't have a width either :(

Comment: I don't believe it is possible without javascript at the moment. Would you like to see how it could be done in js?

Comment: @Zeaklous it couldn't hurt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something [*like this*](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/48/), which resizes the container only if another box can fit/not fit depending on the window size. This functionality is not currently possible in pure CSS as far as I know because CSS can't scale down in segments (the full width of the box) based on dynamic content

The CSS

```
#container {
    background:blue;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    /* for ie6/7: */
    *display: inline;
    zoom:1;
}
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and the pure javascript

```
var boxAmount = 0;
var newWidth = 0;
setNewWidth();

window.onresize = function () {
    setNewWidth();
};

function setNewWidth() {
    var outerContainer = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var outerWidth = outerContainer.offsetWidth;
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var boxWidth = box[0].offsetWidth;
    var innerContainer = document.getElementById('container');
    var containerPadding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(innerContainer, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'), 10) 
    +  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(innerContainer, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right'), 10);

    boxAmount = (outerWidth - containerPadding) / (boxWidth + containerPadding);
    boxAmount = Math.floor(boxAmount);
    if (boxAmount <= box.length) {
        newWidth = boxAmount * boxWidth + boxAmount * 5;
    }
    innerContainer.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
}
```

[Here is a version if there is another container around the boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/50/)

[Here is a jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yXxD6/49/) for those who are interested

Comment: You might want to explain how `boxAmount` is computed and why `5` is hard coded.  Is 5 related to the 5px used in padding and margin?

Comment: Yes, I will change that. One second

Comment: This question comes up quite often (I answered a similar one months ago).  It is good to see a native JavaScript solution because not everyone uses jQuery.