# Making a div's width exactly that of the divs inside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Bear with me. I know this has been asked and I tried all the answers in the threads I found an none did the trick for me.

I have a div (container) that has some divs inside (sprites). The container has a responsive width but the sprites don't. Depending on the viewport, the container can fit anywhere from 2 to 4 of the sprites. Now, what I want is for the container to adopt the width of the last div in a certain line, not the whole width available.

This is the basical HTML look:

```
<div class="contenedorRubros">
<div class="sprite-rubros sprite-rubros_entretenimiento imgRubro" id="Entretenimiento">
</div></div>
```

The CSS looks basically like this:

```
.contenedorRubros {
padding-top:1%;
padding-bottom:1%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}
.sprite-rubros {
background:url(SPRITE) no-repeat top left;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:1%;
padding-bottom:1%;}
```

This is the "simplified" problem in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mampy3000/t6Duc/

Please help! Sorry if a solution for this has been specifically adressed, but I tried a bunch and feel like the problem might be too complicated for me.

Thanks!

PS: Tried solutions to similar problems involving display:table, display:inline-block; float, etc. No good so far!

Comment: Can you identify which element is not displaying correctly with an id? It's difficult to follow the description here.  Also note you are duplicating IDs across these divs, IDs should be unique.

Comment: To simplify the problem I just took one of the divs and multiplied it. In reality they are all different pointing to a different part of the sprite. 

My issue is that I want the contenedorRubros to wrap itself around the divs inside so as to center it instead of it leaving a big chunk of space in the right side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make inline-block shrink to contents on overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068653/make-inline-block-shrink-to-contents-on-overflow)

Comment: Spot on. But can you give me a hand? I don't get what I'm doing wrong, it still won't work...: http://jsfiddle.net/mampy3000/t6Duc/